# Impersonation using httpmodule, threading issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, impersonation, httpmodule, integrated-pipeline-mode

We have as SAAS application that runs for multiple customers at the same time. All customers use the same application, and by checking the URL used to access the application, users are redirected to the correct data for the organization.

Underwater, every organization has their own database. To make sure that users don't accidentally end up in the wrong database, we want to impersonate the request being executed to a user that only has access to the correct database. We used to do this and this worked beautifully on IIS in classic mode.

However, in integrated pipeline mode, we run into a threading issue. We use an HTTP module to impersonate the request to the correct user in the "PreRequestHandlerExecute" event. The problem that (apparently) there is no guarantee that this method is executed in the same thread as the handler that actually processes the request. This causes the impersonation to sometimes not work because the thread processing the request is not impersonated.

I've created a test project in GitHub (https://github.com/PaulVrugt/ImpersonationExample/tree/master/ImpersonationTest) demonstrating the issue (apologies for the vb.net, but you'll get the idea). When you run the example connected to an IIS using integrated pipeline mode, you'll see that sometimes the impersonated user is not used, and each time it is not used, the managedthreadid of the thread processing the request is different from the thread used in the httpmodule.

Now that I understand why it "sometimes" doesn't work, I begin to suspect I'm going about this all wrong. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

We've already tried to impersonate in the prerequesthandler in the global.asax, but that results in the same issue.